# local python proxy for web browser

Tags: python, localhost, web-crawler, proxy-server

Hello Guys! Using firefox plugins I can capture headers. I want to do it in python: I need to change the browser proxy settings to localhost:8080 (or any port), then every request made by browser should pass through python script which is actually running on my machine. This script should be able capture headers, capture links in web page and so on. I know that web application scanners do so, but how can I do it in python. Can you suggest any start place, reading? I just want to learn about it and implement one.

Comment: I made a simple proxy with python last year, but I can't find where I put the script :(. Anyway, implementing http part is very easy, but supporting https (via CONNECT method) is quite difficult. I never have enough motivation to implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [python-proxy](http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/). Googling for ["python proxy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20proxy) also yields tons of results.

If you want to write one from scratch it's also not too hard. You can use [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html) to listen for new connections, make it multithreaded via [`SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) and then implement `do_GET` and `do_CONNECT` (possibly also `do_POST` and `do_HEAD`). In those methods you need to extract the URL from `self.path`, send a HTTP request to that URL (preferably using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) package, it's much more comfortable than urllib) and send the response back to the client.

Comment: I want to learn buliding such servers, so your answer is good, but if I am new to this stuff, where can I start learning, I think just reading python docs will not be enough.

Comment: Reading the docs and looking at existing code using those things is usually enough.